# regex: match a specific character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have these three expressions:

1. [$€-2]\ #,##0.00;\-[$€-2]\ #,##0.00
2. [$USD]\ #,##0.00;\-[$USD]\ #,##0.00
3. *-[$$-409]* #,##0.00* ;*-[$$-409]* \-#,##0.00\ ;*-[$$-409]* \"-\"??_ ;*-@*

I'm trying to match:

1. €
2. USD
3. $

I tried to use `[^\d\s, \.]` and `\p{Sc}` but it is not working. How can I match these specific characters?

Comment: which regex engine are you using? are you using python, php, or java?

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Try `USD|\p{Sc}` if it supports Unicode category classes

Comment: Try `\$|€|USD`?

Comment: Maybe if you want do do a global search you would also add `g` at the end: `/€|USD|\$/g`

Comment: Nice, but the expressions could have another symbols like `£` `¥` etc etc... There are some regex that evolve all thats currency symbols?

Comment: @RodrigoAlmeida Read Wiktor's comment above.

Comment: In RoR, [`USD|\p{Sc}` pattern works](https://rubular.com/r/kTLefj4peNGneq).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\bUSD\b|\p{Sc}
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/BkebbbnxNSICJ2).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `USD` - a `USD` string
- `\b` - word boundary
- `|` - or
- `\p{Sc}` - any Unicode currency char.

You may want to expand the pattern to

```
\b(?:USD|GBP|EUR|JPY|CHF|SEK|DKK|NOK|SGD|HKD|AUD|TWD|NZD|CNY|KRW|INR|CAD|VEF|EGP|THB|IDR|PKR|MYR|PHP|MXN|VND|CZK|HUF|PLN|TRY|ZAR|ILS|ARS|CLP|BRL|RUB|QAR|AED|COP|PEN|CNH|KWD|SAR)\b|\p{Sc}
```

to support more common currency abbreviations.